# Cordova plugin local notification behaves differently on different devices (not appearing at all, having no sounds,...)

Tags: android, cordova, notifications, cordova-plugins

I am a total newbie when it comes to writing code for Android Apps. Having said that, I have set up an app for my research using an [open-source one](http://www.experiencesampler.com/index.html). This app is used to collect daily data from participants (an Experience Sampling method). Six notifications per day are to be sent to the participants which would alert them to fill out the questionnaires. To repurpose the app for my research, I only had to change two files (a .js file and a .html file) and I know next to nothing about the other files of the app.

The problem is that on different devices I get different behaviors regarding the notifications. On some devices, notifications appear without a problem, some others need adjustments done to the app's setting to have sounds. The most problematic cases are the ones where the notifications appear erratically, like not arriving as scheduled or only appearing after the app is opened once. Depending on the phone's model, the setting differs. I have tweaked one of the phones showing the latter problem, but with no result. I also wasn't able to detect a pattern. Most of the devices showing notification problems are Huawei, but not all. The Android versions are also different (I have been able to test the app on 26 different phones).

This is how I schedule the notifications (the simple version with only 3 notifs):

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule([
      {icon: 'ic_launcher', id: a, text: 'Time to answer the questions!', title: 'Daily Survey', trigger: {at: new Date(epoch1)}},
      {icon: 'ic_launcher', id: b, text: 'Time to answer the questions!', title: 'Daily Survey', trigger: {at: new Date(epoch2)}},
      {icon: 'ic_launcher', id: c, text: 'Time to answer the questions!', title: 'Daily Survey', trigger: {at: new Date(epoch3)}}
    ]);
```

A username is asked the first time the participant opens the app and then all notifications are scheduled ahead of time.

I am reasonably experienced with programming in general (mostly c++ and python) and therefore, know my way around code, usually. What I'm hoping for is for someone to point me in the direction that I need to work on and check in order to fix this problem. The priority is to be able to fix it in the code and not to burden the participants with adjusting the settings. However, I would be content if I could come up with clear instructions for tweaking the settings and getting the app to work.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I think this issue should be opened at the repo's on github, besides no one can really fix your issue. "Some phones" is just too random....

Comment: Thank you for your response. Before posting a question here, I checked the repo and saw that recent questions were left unanswered for a long time and thought that probably no one has time to check and answer the issues posted there.

Comment: Also, the reason for the ambiguities in the problem is that I wasn't able to find a pattern... Notifications mostly don't appear on Huawei devices but there are ones that work. In another example, the app works fine on one Samsung A51 and not on another (with the same version of Android). As I am not experienced in Android app development, I don't have a clue what could be the cause and where I should look.